# how come my html is not adding through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, session, session-storage

Here is the js file, itemsbox.innerHTML should take the html , but it's not taking it's just showing nothing, I mean the javascript file itself is not working..

```
for(var x=0;x<sessionStorage.length;x++){
    var a = sessionStorage.key(x);
    var key_var = sessionStorage.getItem(a);
    itemsbox.innerHTML += '<div id="item" style="background-color:yellow;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
        <span id="close1" onclick="close_1()">x</span>
        <center><span>'+key_var+'</span></center>
        </div><br>';
}
```

Comment: Not much information to work from here. Any errors thrown?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You need to post more of your code. For example we don't see how you set the variable for itemsbox.